# Fix Offset on JQuery Drag Function

Tags: jquery

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wLXsp/1/

I can drag a div and have it move nice and smoothly, but there's this annoying offset problem I have that I'm having trouble resolving.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var onmove = false;

$('.rect').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    onmove = 1
});

$(document).on('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
    if (onmove) {
        $('.rect').css({
            'top': e.pageY,
            'left': e.pageX
        });
    }
}).on('mouseup touchend', function() {
    onmove = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
var onmove = false;
var x1;var y1;var x2;var y2;var x3; var y3;

$('.rect').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    onmove = 1;
    x1 = event.clientX;
    y1 = event.clientY;
    x3 = parseInt($('.rect').css('left'));
    y3 = parseInt($('.rect').css('top'));
});

$(document).on('mousemove touchmove', function(e) {
    if (onmove) {
            x2 = e.clientX;
            y2 = e.clientY;

            distX = x2 - x1;
            distY = y2 - y1;

            var newX = x3 + distX;
            var newY = y3 + distY;

            $('.rect').css('left', newX);
            $('.rect').css('top', newY);

    }
}).on('mouseup touchend', function() {
    onmove = false;
});
```